# Number of degrees of freedom for a gaseous mixture

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, degrees-of-freedom

I came across the formula to find the number of degrees of freedom in a gaseous mixture which is as follows:

$$f_\mathrm{mix}
=\frac{\sum n_if_i}{\sum n_i}$$

Now it has been mentioned in this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eukipthV6Kg) I saw that this is only applicable if the temperature of all mixed gases is equal. Then, the formula for the final temperature has been derived in a case where there is no change in internal energy, but the temperature of the gases mixed is not equal, which comes out to be:

$$T_\mathrm{mix}
=\frac{\sum n_if_iT_i}{\sum n_if_i}$$

I tried applying the principle of conservation of internal energy myself to find out $f_\mathrm{mix}$ which led me to the equation:

$$f_\mathrm{mix}T_\mathrm{mix}
=\frac{\sum n_if_iT_i}{\sum n_i}$$

Now using the value of $T_\mathrm{mix}$, I found the equation for $f_\mathrm{mix}$, which came out to be the first equation in case of all the temperatures being equal. My confusion lies in whether this result is correct and if the formula can be used in any case of constant internal energy or if the temperature must be equal for all gases in order for the formula to be applicable?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to calculate.

Comment: Suppose an insulating container with n1, n2,... mol each of gases at temperatures T1, T2... and with degrees of freedom f1, f2... separated by insulating walls. If the walls are removed and no work is done on the system throughout the process, I want to calculate the final temperature and number of degrees of freedom of the mixture of gases formed.

Comment: (1) Are there reactions going on? Without reactions the degrees of freedom are constant b/c they are properties of the particles. For example, a point particle has three translational degrees of motion, that's before *and* after mixing. (2) In order to have $T_1$, $T_2$ and so on for each component you must be assuming they are contained in different boxes before mixing. Is this the case? (3) When you write $f_\text{mix} T$, where does this come from? Energy is $\frac{1}{2} k_B f_\text{mix} T$, are you starting with energy?

Answer (score 0):

Temperature in equilibrium statistical mechanics is a collective property that characterizes the entire system, not individual particles. We do not speak of the temperature of the particles, rather we say that the particles belong to an ensemble with temperature $T$. Similarly, it does not make sense to write $\frac{k_B}{2}f_i T_i$ , we write $\frac{k_B}{2}f_i T$ and
$$
   E^\text{tot} = \frac{\bar f}{2} n k_B T
$$